# Deploying WAR FILE in Microsoft Azure Web App

Tags: java, tomcat, azure

I have created a Microsoft azure web app and configured java version 8 and tomcat latest available. As per their [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-add-app/) , I have uploaded my WAR file to d:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ROOT .

[Screenshot of MY Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bezJr.png)

wen iam trying to access, giving me a 404 error.Please help me to fix this

[image]

Comment: Isn't ROOT a webabb on it's own? Try deploying to wwwroot/webapps/

Comment: Thanks jan. It got resolved :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as documentation say :

> you can upload your application by placing your WAR in the webapps folder.

in tomcat's webapp folder you copy war files, tomcat detects the presence of one of those files and unzip it to a folder corresponding to the name you chose for your file, so if you copy toto.war to

$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/

after tomcat deployed your war file the folder will look like

```
$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/toto.war
$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/toto  (folder being the unzipped version of your file)
```

ROOT folder is just a special case of that for the webapplication that is served without using a context.

Comment: Thank You @frederic . It got resolved .Thank you very much

Comment: Does the tomcat do this on its own or we have to do something on Azure portal?(I'm sorry to ask this silly question, a beginner) @Frederic Close